# Curl Get Request Limit to Jetty RESTful API

Tags: rest, curl, get, jetty, restful-url

What is the maximum length of a URL sent in curl to Jetty? Where is it documented, and is it configurable?

I'm implementing a RESTful API on Jetty and will be expecting requests for 1 to 600 accounts. I would like to know the limitations I'm up against. I think you can configure requestHeaderSize on a Jetty Server, is there a Max in Jetty?

If it better to just use POST instead, even though we're not posting any data to the server for update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using http `GET` for the data submission, then it has nothing to do with curl. Rather it depends upon the server, about how many data its expecting. For most of the servers the default value is 8K. So if your server supports this amount of data through `GET`, then curl can handle it as well.